# Automate csv dump into new Postgres tables

Tags: python, postgresql

I have multiple thousands of csvs and each csv has over 10000 records. I'm looking for the most efficient way to dump this data into tables in Postgres DB with minimal time and effort.

Comment: What methods have you found on your searches? How did they work out?

Comment: Similar questions have been answered already. Please look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050097/copy-data-from-csv-to-postgresql-using-python and also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646305/efficient-way-to-import-a-lot-of-csv-files-into-postgresql-db

Comment: It s not the same as the previously opened questions because:
The old questions give you a way to import a SINGLE csv file into postgres. But in my case, I want to automate the import of a very large number of files where there are 2 manual processes involved: 1. Create a new table 2. Import the csv into this new table. 
I want to accomplish these 2 steps in one procedure for multiple thousands of files through automation.

Comment: In other words, I want to be able to create the tables on the fly and assign table names as source file names and then import data from source file into the table created for a bulk of files.

Comment: @sulabhchaturvedi the links you have provided have answers to tackle a single file import into a new table with manual table creation. But my question is different.

Comment: @roganjosh most of the methods I found out on research only ell me how to import a single csv at a time into a manually created table. 
What I need is this:

A script/method that would automate the following steps for 10000 files:
1. Create a new table with the name of the data file
2. Import data from the data file into the new table created in step 1.

Comment: @PriyaSreetharan -. - Please go through the link carefully. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646305/efficient-way-to-import-a-lot-of-csv-files-into-postgresql-db. Here the user is talking about multiple cSV import, This is the extract of question  ---->> " I see plenty of examples of importing a CSV into a PostgreSQL db, but what I need is an efficient way to import 500,000 CSV's into a single PostgreSQL db. Each CSV is a bit over 500KB (so grand total of approx 272GB of data)" <<---

Comment: @sulabhchaturvedi Thanks for sharing the link firstly. I went through the same, but it won't be the same as my use case as the data structure of my table is not identical as his case was.

Comment: @PriyaSreetharan - Okay. Then, I would suggest write a new question and elaborate it to an extent where people can understand what exactly are you looking for. Also, share the research you have done like you just commented. This will help you to get an answer and others to answer more appropriately - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @sulabhchaturvedi I have opened another ticket explaining the problem in depth. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

COPY is usually the best solution. Depends of your constraints.

```
COPY table_name FROM 'path_readable_by_postgres/file.cvs';
```

And you can `cat` your files in a big one to import data quickly.

Look ta https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html for more details.

Comment: Answered also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table

Comment: as @zeevb pointed out this is same answer as provided by a different user in the link

Comment: I have multiple thousands of files. I don't want to manually add all the file names. ALso, for this command to work, I already need to have the table created, which I don't have. If I were to manually create, I'd have to create multiple thousands of table and it would be extremely time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas library to read and transform data (if needed), sqlalchemy to create postgres engine and psycopg2 to load data into postgresql. I assume, that you've already created tables in Postgres DB. Try something like the code below

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
# Drop "Unnamed: 0", as it often causes problems in writing to table
pd.read_csv({path/to/file.csv}, index_col={index_column}).drop(["Unnamed: 0"], axis=1)
# Now simply load your data into database
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:port/database')
try:
    pd_table.to_sql({'name_of_table_in_postgres_db'}, engine, if_exists='append')
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    print('Closed connection to the database')
```

Comment: So, no I haven't yet created the tables.
The code above reads one csv and dumps it to a new table and I can loop it out for all the files?

Comment: The above code throws an error in line
engine = try:

Comment: `engine = try:` why are you using assignment here?

Comment: `engine = try:` --- sorry, I have lost some code, now it should be okay

Comment: The code above adds one csv into postgresql table, created earlier. You can loop it to add all csv files into table.