# Create multiple non-identical postgres tables dynamically from csvs and dump csv data using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have multiple thousands of csvs that I need to dump into postgres as a table each. But the problem is, these tables are not identical in structure. I'm looking for a way I can create the table on the fly from the structure of the csv and dump the csv into the table created. If I were to do it manually, it would involve 2 steps:
 1. Create the table based on the csv data structure
 2. Dump the csv data into the created table

But since I have thousands of these csvs, it would extremely inefficient to do this manually. I'm looking for a way I could dynamically create a postgres table based on a csv structure and dump data into this table and automate this entire process for thousands of files.

Most of the research I did points me to PG commands to dump data into a single existing table, but those solutions won't work here because the number of tables is huge here.

[Efficient way to import a lot of csv files into PostgreSQL db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646305/efficient-way-to-import-a-lot-of-csv-files-into-postgresql-db) - This pointed me to a similar problem, but his tables are all identical in structure, unlike mine.

Comment: extract the header from the csv and then use that to make your columns.

Comment: you can use pandas to read the csv files and create the tables without having to specify individual schemas. the specific functions are `pandas.read_csv` & `pandas.to_sql`